# In MS Visual Studio watch window, how to format a function-returned int as 4 char values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, watch-window

If I put an int into Visual Studio's watch window, I can use various format additions to display it in different ways. So if I have "int myVariable = 10;" in the code, I can put "myVariable,x" into the watch window to have it display as hex. Likewise, "myVariable,c" makes it take the low byte and display it as a character. [All the format tricks are documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2017)

Now, with an int, I can do this:

```
(char*)(&myVariable),4
```

The ",4" says to display 4 values of the array. That will let me see the integer as a string of 4 characters -- this is some old software I'm working with that has a bunch of 4-character encodings. But I can't do that trick with a value returned from a function:

```
(char*)(&foo()),4
```

because I cannot take the address of the returned function. Watch window reports an error.

**Does anyone know a trick where I can put a function into the watch window and format its integer return value as a string of characters?**

Comment: If you just want to look at the value returned from a function, you can probably find a temporary variable that the return is assigned to. But I don't think you can "put a function into the watch window." Visual Studio would need to call your function every time it wants to update the display, and I don't think it does that kind of thing.

Comment: @Tim putting a function in watch window works just fine. Yes, it calls the function. Very useful for debugging.

Comment: I do not believe you can manipulate the function return value displayed in the locals window but you could copy the actual return value to the watch window and do so there.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I cannot take the address of an integer constant in the watch window, so I still cannot cast it as a (char*), so, no, I still cannot manipulate it to see it as four chars. (Even if that did work, it would still be problematic if I have to modify the watch window every time I break into code... the whole point is to have the watch show me the value as it changes. I just want to see that as characters.)